# How to get static on CRT screen instead of black screen?

Tags: tv, static, crt

The TV in question is a Sony Trinitron KV-14M1D CRT. I know it sounds backwards but I need the screen to show white noise for a project (oscillograph); but there seems to be a static block that displays a black screen when static is present. Do you think there could be a workaround by plugging something into the antenna input to trick the TV or something like that? I don’t have the schematics unfortunately.

Comment: how about a computer with a white noise program?

Comment: Can you use a different (less intelligent) monitor?

Comment: Have you gone through the TV user manual to see if there is any setting to turn this feature off?

Comment: I'll bet audio is muted along with black-screen too. In radio, the circuit is called **squelch**. In a TV, this kind of squelch signal detector could be done many ways, so how you "trick" it would require schematics.

Comment: _"I need the screen to show white noise for a project (oscillograph)"_ - Exactly why do you need this 'static' for your project?

Comment: what channel is the TV on? sounds like you have it in a video input mode (which show black when unconnected) instead of a tuner input (which shows static if not connected). AFAIK, sony never had an auto-squelch on CRT's analog tuners.

Comment: @glen_geek thank you, I've been looking all over to get what the process was called to no avail. Since asking the question, I found that the tv even skips the empty channels when an antenna is present, so I think it goes deeper than a simple circuit. thanks anyway

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'm not sure actually. I was going to seperate vertical deflection coil wires and connect my source to them; so I figured tv should keep shooting electrons so that I could see something on the screen. But I have no idea how the tv would behave if I were to do that. Do you think it could work?

Comment: @user253751 the tv has a scart input, I could feed visuals through that but I realy would like this to be a stand-alone unit if possible

Comment: @dandavis much to my surprise this old tv I got dirt cheap does actually something sensible which I need it not to. So yes, it does it on both video input mode and tuner input mode.

Comment: interesting, must be a european feature. there might be a setting in the service menu (on remote press display, 5, volup, [power] when off).

Comment: So you are trying to turn the TV into an oscilloscope, and need a bright beam? Connect an antenna to the TV, tune it to a station, then turn the brightness up and contrast and colour down, or make a composite video generator that generates a white screen using a small MCU. http://www.suppertime.co.uk/blogmywiki/2017/01/arduino-tvout/

Comment: If you feel like a project, people have managed to generate valid TV signals from cheap microcontrollers, you could use one of those and program it to generate white noise. (Not a trivial thing to do)